# Admin menu path to: Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, supee-9767

After installing patch SUPEE-9767 the *"Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout"* warning appeared and from the link provided in that warning I was able to enable *Form Key Validation*.

But, after having some issues in the checkout process I would like to try to disable it and check if everything comes back to normal.

The big problem here is that I cannot find where the option is in the admin menu.

I seem to recall it was in:

**System > Configuration > Advanced > Security > Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout**

But if it was there, now it has disappeared. Do I recall it wrong or what might be the issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Close! It's under **System > Configuration > Admin > Security > Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout**

Comment: I enabled form key validation and now the checkout is broken. It will not advance past STEP 1 (billing info). v1.9.3.1

Comment: @yldziner There's a bug in Magento: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177035/supee-9767-patch-ce-1-9-3-3-one-page-checkout-customer-registration-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: I'm not seeing that setting on the System->Configuration->Admin page (under Security or elsewhere on the page) in an install of v1.9.1.0. Was that added in a later version?

Comment: I'm also not seeing this setting - although I've found it in other installations. I'm also running - Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Comment: I too am not seeing the setting after the patch install from 1.9.1.0

Comment: @yldziner: did you solve this problem because it look's the same as my problem

Answer (score 1):

**How I fix it on Magento 1.9.3.7. with php70**

1. disable Form Key-just ignore the security message (if your theme does not support formkey -ask from whoever you bought it if theme supports formkey validation)
   To disable go to Configuration>GENERAL>WEB>Security>set to NO
2. Fix your Session Cache Settings in Configuration>GENERAL>WEB>Session Cookie Management to:
   Cookie  lifetime=3600 -default
   cookie path -leave empty
   cookie domain  -leave empty
   use HTTP Only -set to YES  (it's ok-because in url secure and unsecure i have https for both + ssl
   Cookie Restriction Mode -Set NO
3. Clear Cache
4. Clear Session logs (go to your public_html/var/session folder in hosting and delete everything ((your cron jobs should be set also for this folder -check with hosting
5. clear browser cache
   login or do the checkout-is it working?
   If not -disable temporary any captcha plugin and test again