# SUPEE-9767 Patch/CE 1.9.3.3 - One Page Checkout - Customer Registration issue

Tags: security, patches, ce-1.9.2.4, magento1.9.3, supee-9767

On a clean, vanilla install of Magento 1.9.2.4, patched with SUPEE-8788, SUPEE-9652 and SUPEE-9767, and with the new 'Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout' setting turned on, **following a successful new customer registration checkout on the default One Page Checkout, no new customer is created and the customer is not logged in, although the order goes through fine.**

Turning the 'Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout' setting off makes this work again. Has anybody else had this issue? It doesn't seem to matter which shipping/payment methods are used.

I've since tried this with a fresh, unaltered installation of Magento 1.9.3.3 and it seems to have the same issue. When registering a new customer through the one page checkout, no customer is created even through the order goes through fine, as long as the 'Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout' setting is switched on.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ok here's the real bug fix I came up with.

Edit `/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js` and edit the `setMethod()` method by replacing:

```
setMethod: function(){
    if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
        this.method = 'guest';
        new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'guest'}}
        );
        Element.hide('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing', true);
    }
    else if($('login:register') && ($('login:register').checked || $('login:register').type == 'hidden')) {
        this.method = 'register';
        new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'register'}}
        );
        Element.show('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing', true);
    }
    else{
        alert(Translator.translate('Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest').stripTags());
        return false;
    }
    document.body.fire('login:setMethod', {method : this.method});
},
```

With:

```
setMethod: function(){
    var formKey = $('checkout-step-login').select('[name=form_key]')[0].value;
    if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
        this.method = 'guest';
        new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'guest', form_key:formKey}}
        );
        Element.hide('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing', true);
    }
    else if($('login:register') && ($('login:register').checked || $('login:register').type == 'hidden')) {
        this.method = 'register';
        new Ajax.Request(
            this.saveMethodUrl,
            {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'register', form_key:formKey}}
        );
        Element.show('register-customer-password');
        this.gotoSection('billing', true);
    }
    else{
        alert(Translator.translate('Please choose to register or to checkout as a guest').stripTags());
        return false;
    }
    document.body.fire('login:setMethod', {method : this.method});
},
```

That'll do it while we're waiting for the v2 of the patch

Comment: Nice. I was too lazy to work out the prototype to find an appropriate input field.

Comment: @PeterO'Callaghan yeah prototype is painful to work when you're used to jQuery ^^

Comment: What happens when you have no element with the name "form_key" in your checkout at this point? How big are the chances that will occur?

Comment: @ArjenMiedema as said in private: the form key is automatically added on every page regardless of the new config setting. If you don't have it, you either unpatcvhed, running an old version or a vulnerable theme so either way you don't need that bug fix ^^

Comment: @Arjen Miedema If you have no form key input element and have patched then I have found some checkout modules overwriting the fieldset element or disabling input elements with css. Check the element in your browser inspector to make sure client side/dynamic code is not changing it. If it is being changed, find out what is changing it.

Comment: @paj thanks for letting me know. Implemented it for several shops now with no issues

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism: I tried your way but that didn't helped me, any idea?

Comment: @AnuragKhandelwal ensure the js file is not cached by the browser. Also ensure you don't rewrite that file in your custom theme

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism: My bad, it was caching issue.. Thanks a bundle buddy..

Comment: Unfortunately this is a better fix for the issue than the actual v2 that magento brought out. So I will use v2 with this instead of the "fix" they used

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, I did the same but not working for me. till order place successfully but custome account not created in admin.

Answer (score 15):

When you select register and continue, the JS script calls `checkout.setMethod()`, which is located in `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js`. From there we can see it makes an AJAX POST request to `this.saveMethodUrl`, but the only paramter it passes is `method`. If we look at `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveMethodAction`, which is the target of that AJAX request, we can see that the patch added:

```
if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        return;
}
```

Since `_validateFormKey` looks for a `form_key` parameter in the request, and since the JS `setMethod` request didn't send this when it made the AJAX request, it's simply returning early and doing nothing. Back to the `setMethod` function and we can see that since it doesn't attempt to do anything with a return value, nothing else happens and the JS continues. At this point the JS has set `this.method = 'register'` but the quote hasn't been updated, so `checkout_method` is the default 'guest'.

Since the JS knows the customer selected register, it displays the password fields, so on the face of it, it looks like you're registering. But as far as the PHP side is concerned, it's a guest checkout, so it doesn't create the customer when checkout is complete.

*Edit:* the simplest fix is to comment out those three lines from saveMethodAction. The more correct/complex solution is that `setMethod` should be grabbing the form_key from the page and sending it with the AJAX request.

Comment: Could you please provide the path where we can find : this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey

Comment: skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js doesnt contain that function.

Comment: is this caused by a missing form key or is this a js problem because I have a similar problem affecting one page checkout where the savepayment ajax call returns null when formkeys on checkout are enabled but I cannot find any unpatched files or missing form keys?

Comment: @peter, do you think this issue is a Bug in the patch? If so, you think magento will release Version 2 of the patch?

Comment: The code snippet checking the form_key is from `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`. It's caused by the JS making the request not sending the form_key. It is a bug with the patch. I suspect there will have to be a v2.

Comment: @PeterO'Callaghan Fantastic!

Comment: Or until patch v2, just disable the System / Configuration / Admin -> Security -> "Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout" setting to 0

This will bring a notice, but after patch v2 we can re-enable it

Comment: Thanks for digging a bit deeper, Peter. Hopefully someone from Magento will pick this up or notice the bug report and we'll get a v2.

Answer (score 3):

Full credits go to Peter for the solution! I would like to point out step by step instruction what to change.

Go to 
**app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php**

Locate:

```
 public function saveMethodAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment out the line with /* */ tags.

```
 public function saveMethodAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }

    /*if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
        return;
    }*/
```

Comment: This is wrong, you are commenting out the one which patch added. As far as I am aware of this patch, js request should send `form key` instead. We should report this fault (patch) to magento core team.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri This may be wrong but it works! and Yes, magento team should be aware by now. Double message them if you can.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri I agree with you. Commenting these 2 lines removes the problem, but removes also the patch goal. I've got the same issue and cannot understand how to fix it properly for the moment...

Comment: Rather than commenting out the `isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled()` you could just disable the setting in the admin however the best solution is Raphaels: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/177125/2671

Comment: @DanCarlyon What ever Raphael did is great job. I just provided instruction for the short-term fix suggested by Peter, days before Magento acknowledged there is a problem. I agree is a not the ideal solution but rather a fix just as disabling form-keys from back-end.

Answer (score 1):

A good point to start:

[Security Patch SUPEE-9767 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues)

You need to update your template files. Please note there are only a few hours from the release of this patch and for the moment we have to deal with what is public. I am pretty sure in the next days things will get clarified.

EDIT: Thank you for down voting! I am sorry I cannot give a solution in 8 hours from releasing this patch.

Comment: Yes, I've gone through all the template files on the installation where I spotted the problem. I've updated the question above - on a test vanilla installation of Magento 1.9.3.3 with no modifications I seem to be having the same issue. The test 1.9.2.4 installation was using the default (fresh, unmodified) package/theme too.

Comment: I tried with 1.7.0.2 and same thing, customers never gets registered when Forms keys are Enabled.

Comment: I will do some investigations comparing 1.9.2.4 with 1.9.3.3 and see what are the differences. I did not install from scratch 1.9.3.3 yet. I will post the report in the mentioned link above.

Comment: update this post with a solution if find. I am looking into it myself.

Comment: Will update if I find the issue; have raised a bug report at Magento as this seems to be a problem with an unmodified 1.9.3.3 install.

Comment: That Bug tracker at Magento is not the way to report, it is useless. I did it before many years, giving solutions, and nothing was changed in the code. Nobody is listening there, but they listen in Magento 2! Always I found solutions in other places than Magento website. My advice is to do some tests before updating your production websites. With the new issues I think we will see a new update sooner than we think. The same thing happened between 1.9.3.0 and 1.9.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the patch @ Raphael at Digital Pianism.

For convenience, I created a diff so you can quickly apply the patch.

```
 skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js | 9 +++++----
 1 file changed, 5 insertions(+), 4 deletions(-)

diff --git a/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js b/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
index 8935793af..9ccbe61a9 100644
--- a/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
+++ b/skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js
@@ -165,20 +165,21 @@ Checkout.prototype = {
     },

     setMethod: function(){
+        var formKey = $('checkout-step-login').select('[name=form_key]')[0].value;
         if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
             this.method = 'guest';
-            var request = new Ajax.Request(
+            new Ajax.Request(
                 this.saveMethodUrl,
-                {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'guest'}}
+                {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'guest', form_key:formKey}}
             );
             Element.hide('register-customer-password');
             this.gotoSection('billing', true);
         }
         else if($('login:register') && ($('login:register').checked || $('login:register').type == 'hidden')) {
             this.method = 'register';
-            var request = new Ajax.Request(
+            new Ajax.Request(
                 this.saveMethodUrl,
-                {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'register'}}
+                {method: 'post', onFailure: this.ajaxFailure.bind(this), parameters: {method:'register', form_key:formKey}}
             );
             Element.show('register-customer-password');
             this.gotoSection('billing', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Version 2 of the SUPEE-9767 patch](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2034) was released earlier today, along with [Magento CE 1.9.3.4](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2033). V2 fixes a number of issues, including this checkout registration bug.

You can upgrade to the latest version (1.9.3.4), or revert V1 and then apply V2 of the patch. Either option will resolve the issue.

The official change in V2 is effectively the same as Peter O'Callaghan described, removing the three lines added to `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveMethodAction`.