# Onepage checkout stuck on billing section

Tags: onepage-checkout

I am having an issue with Magento's onepage checkout.

Everything was working fine, I had tested a few orders with success. However, today I merged css/js from the magento admin and afterwards I noticed that during the onepage checkout process it gets stuck at the billing address.

I "unmerged", cleared magento cache, cleared browser cache and cookies and still the issue remains.

There are no errors in firefox developer tools and I see the following under the network tab when clicking "Continue":

```
POST https://www.example.com/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/ 200 OK   
POST https://www.example.com/checkout/onepage/getAdditional/ 200 OK
```

I have randomly tried the solutions of "similar" issues that I found while searching magento stackexchange and nothing has worked or hasn't been relevant to my installation.

The issue does not occur with the default theme so I am assuming it is to do with the custom theme being used.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the `saveBilling` and `getAdditional` should return a JSON response. IN your case, for some reason it returns an empty response. That's all I could see on a first glance. Try debugging step by step these `saveBillingAction` and `getAdditionalAction` methods in the onepageController.

Comment: Ok thank you Marius. So that could be to do with core magento as it invlolves `prototype.js`? I am trying to remember whether I had done any test orders after the last security update I installed from magento. I shall look in to that!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This issue ended up being related to the security update supee-9767.

Although, the issue it was causing for me was different than what has been reported in other posts, well the ones I came across in my search anyways.

The temporary solution to see if this is actually the problem:

`System => Configuration => Admin => Security`

and:

> Turning the 'Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout' setting off makes this work again.

As mentioned here:

[SUPEE-9767 Patch/CE 1.9.3.3 - One Page Checkout - Customer Registration issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177035/supee-9767-patch-ce-1-9-3-3-one-page-checkout-customer-registration-issue)

Unfortunately, the fixes in the answers provided didn't "solve" this specific issue for me without disabling the above option, which I wasn't comfortable with as it is essentially going against the patch itself.

However, knowing that it was an issue with my template it was obvious that it didn't have the `formkey` added.

This command finally fixed the problem for me:

```
find -L app/design/frontend -regex '.*\(shipping\|billing\|shipping_method\|payment\).phtml' -exec grep -L formkey {} \; \
  | xargs sed -i 's/<\/form>/<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml("formkey") ?><\/form>/g'
```

I hope this helps someone else out until an update for the patch is released.

Comment: This issue because of formkey is not available in your theme. Please add form key

Comment: Yes, that's what this answer does :)

Comment: @SabeBarker , thanks bro it working awesome just added form key in file.