# Checkout Step Not Working

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I am not able to checkout using onepage checkout. After `BILLING INFORMATION` "Continue" Button don't take me Further Step. In `console`  I can see 

 `http://fashionwithdeals.com/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/   200 OK
 http://fashionwithdeals.com/checkout/onepage/getAdditional/    200 OK`

So what is the problem i can not find ?
can any one help me ?Any kind of Help will appreciate.
I am using magento version :1.9.3.4

Comment: You can look here maybe you have the same issue: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/178304/onepage-checkout-stuck-on-billing-section

Comment: yes that solution work for me... but is this right solution without form key?

Comment: You can also refer this link with Form Key  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/security-patch-supee-9767-possible-issues